# How can I exchange the first and last characters of a string in Java?

Tags: java

I am practicing over the summer to try and get better and I am a little stuck on the following:

http://www.javabat.com/prob/p123384

> Given a string, return a new string where the first and last chars have been exchanged.

---

#### Examples:

```
frontBack("code") → "eodc"
frontBack("a") → "a"
frontBack("ab") → "ba"
```

---

#### Code:

```
public String frontBack(String str) 
{
    String aString = "";
    
    if (str.length() == 0){
        return "";
    }
    
    char beginning = str.charAt(0);
    char end = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);
    
    str.replace(beginning, end);
    str.replace(end, beginning);
    
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than using the [`String.replace`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) method, I'd suggest using the [`String.substring`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) method to get the characters excluding the first and last letter, then concatenating the `beginning` and `end` characters.

Furthermore, the `String.replace` method will replace all occurrences of the specified character, and returns a new `String` with the said replacements. Since the return is not picked up in the code above, the `String.replace` calls really don't do much here.

This is because `String` in Java is immutable, therefore, the `replace` method cannot make any changes to the original `String`, which is the `str` variable in this case.

---

Also to add, this approach won't work well with `String`s that have a length of 1. Using the approach above, a call to `String.substring` with the source `String` having a length of 1 will cause a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, so that will also have to be taken care of as a special case, if the above approach is taken.

Frankly, the approach presented in [indyK1ng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028095/how-can-i-exchange-the-first-and-last-characters-of-a-string-in-java/1028124#1028124), where the `char[]` is obtained from the `String` and performing a simple swap of the beginning and end characters, then making a `String` from the modified `char[]` is starting to sound much more pleasant.

Comment: i tried this by creating a new String and assigning the value

String newString = str.substring(1, str.length() -2);

return end + newString + beginning;

but it didnt work

Comment: didnt work = wouldn't compile saying illegal start of expression <sorry for the previous unclear answer i gave>

Comment: I tried out what I've written and was able to get the compile the code and make it run correctly. "Illegal start of expression" sounds like a compiler error where some token (such as a semicolon) was added or missing.

Answer (score 9):

Strings can be split into an array of chars and can be made with an array of chars.  For more details on String objects, go to the [Java API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) and click on String in the lower left pane.  That pane is sorted alphabetically.

Edit: Since some people are being more thorough, I think I'll give additional details.  Create a char array using String's .toCharArray() method.  Take the first element and store it in a char, swap the first element with the last, and place the element you stored in a char into the last element into the array, then say:

```
String temp = new String(charArray);
```

and return that.  This is assuming that charArray is your array of chars.

Comment: +1, this is a good approach as well. The String.toCharArray method can be used to return a char[].

Comment: I think that going over a char array may be overkill for this problem.  Why not just do some substrings?

Comment: I'm not looping over an array, I'm just converting to one, switching the two which need to be switched and converting it back into a String.  It uses one fewer method call than the substring technique at its fewest method calls.

Answer (score 4):

`String` instances in Java are immutable. This means that you cannot change the characters in a `String`; a different sequence of characters requires a new object. So, when you use the `replace` method, throw away the original string, and use the result of the method instead.

For this method, however, you probably want to convert the `String` instance to an array of characters (`char[]`), which are mutable. After *swapping* the desired characters, create a new `String` instance with that array.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of hints:

- Strings are immutable, meaning they cannot be changed. Hence, `str.replace()` does not change `str`, instead it returns a new string.
- Maybe `replace` isn't the best... Consider `frontBack("abcabc")`: your function, if it were corrected, would replace `'a'` with `'c'` yielding `"cbccbc"`, then `'c'` with `'a'` yielding `"abaaba"`. That's not quite right!

Answer (score 2):

The `replace` method in `String` actually returns a `String`, so if you were to insist on using `replace`, you'd do:

```
beginReplace = str.replace( beginning, end );
endReplace = beginReplace.replace( end, beginning );
return( str );
```

But this actually doesn't solve your **specific** problem, because `replace` replaces **all occurences** of a character in the string with its replacement.

For example, if my string was "apple" and I said "apple".replace( 'p', 'q' ), the resulting string would be "aqqle."

Answer (score 2):

Yet another example <strike>**without creating additional objects**</strike>:

```
if (str.length() > 1) {
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    // replace with swap()
    char first = chars[0];
    chars[0] = chars[chars.length - 1];
    chars[chars.length - 1] = first;
    str = new String(chars);
}

return str;
```

**Edit:** Performing the swap on length = 1 string is no-op.

**Edit 2:** dfa's change to copyValueOf did not make any sense as the Java source says in String.java: "// All public String constructors now copy the data." and the call is just delegated to a string constructor.

Comment: additional object: String.toCharArray() creates "a newly allocated character array" which still is an object.

Comment: True. An user called dfa added that sentence to my answer and made other changes (see edit2). He should have just post his own answer

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex..

```
return str.replaceFirst("(.)(.*)(.)", "$3$2$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another, slightly different, approach, so you get a sense of the spectrum of possibilities.  I commend your attention to the quick exit for short strings (instead of nesting the more-complicated processing in an if() clause), and to the use of String.format(), because it's a handy technique to have in your toolbox, not because it's notably better than regular "+" concatenation in this particular example.

```
public static String exchange(String s) {
    int n = s.length();
    if (n < 2)
        return s;
    return String.format("%s%s%s", s.charAt(n - 1), s.substring(1, n - 1), s.charAt(0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is:

```
public String frontBack(String str) {
  if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
    return str;
  }
  char[] cs = str.toCharArray();
  char first = cs[0];
  cs[0] = cs[cs.length -1];
  cs[cs.length -1] = first;
  return new String(cs);
}
```

Using a character array (watch out for the nasty empty String or null String argument!)

---

Another solution uses StringBuilder (which is usually used to do String manupilation since String itself is immutable.

```
public String frontBack(String str) {
  if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
    return str;
  }
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);  
  char first = sb.charAt(0);
  sb.setCharAt(0, sb.charAt(sb.length()-1));
  sb.setCharAt(sb.length()-1, first);
  return sb.toString();
}
```

---

Yet another approach (more for instruction than actual use) is this one:

```
public String frontBack(String str) {
  if (str == null || str.length() < 2) {
    return str;
  }
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
  String sub = sb.substring(1, sb.length() -1);
  return sb.reverse().replace(1, sb.length() -1, sub).toString();
}
```

Here the complete string is reversed and then the part that should not be reversed is replaced with the substring. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public String frontBack(String input)
{
    return
        input.substring(input.length() - 1) +  // The last character
        input.substring(1, input.length() - 1) +  // plus the middle part
        input.substring(0, 1);                  // plus the first character.
}
```

Comment: I have never ever written a single line of Java ... was just meant as pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a StringBuilder that represents "a mutable sequence of characters".
It has all methods needed to solve the problem: charAt, setCharAt, length and toString.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (s.length < 2) {
   return s;
}
return s.subString(s.length - 1) + s.subString(1, s.length - 2) + s.subString(0, 1);
```

(untested, indexes may be of by one...

Answer (score 0):

```
public String lastChars(String a, String b) {

  if(a.length()>=1&&b.length()>=1){
   String str = a.substring(0,1);
    String str1 =b.substring(b.length()-1);
    return str+str1;
}
else if(a.length()==0&&b.length()==0){
 String v ="@";
String z ="@";
return v+z;
   }
   else if(a.length()==0&&b.length()>=1){

   String s ="@";
   String s1 = b.substring(b.length()-1);
   return s+s1;
   }
   else if(a.length()>=1&&b.length()==0){
   String f= a.substring(0,1);
   String h = "@";
   return f+h;
   }
   return a;
   }
```

Comment: Please explain your code to help others understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
public String frontBack(String str) {
    if (str.length() <= 1) 
        return str;

    String mid = str.substring(1, str.length()-1);

    // last + mid + first
    return str.charAt(str.length()-1) + mid + str.charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class swap 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("no of elements in array");
    int n=s.nextInt();
    int a[]=new int[n];
    System.out.println("Elements");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        a[i]=s.nextInt();
    }
    int b[]=new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        b[i]=a[i];
    }
    int end=n-1;
    b[0]=b[end];
    b[end]=a[0];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(b[i]);
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: Avoid only-code answers. Always add some comment or/and explanations.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (str.length() <= 1) {
  return str;
}

String mid = str.substring(1, str.length()-1);
return str.charAt(str.length()-1) + mid + str.charAt(0);
```

Answer (score -5):

```
    function frontBack(str: string) { 


         return str.slice(str.length - 1) + str.slice(1, -1) + str.slice(0, 1) 

    }
```

Slice will "cut out" the last letter. Counting the length of the string which is `str.length -1`, (plus) the reminder sliced string which starts at index 1 and is the last character which expressed at index -1, (plus) sliced last letter which is at index 0 through index 1.

Comment: This does not look like Java. `str: string` instead of `String string`? And `str.slice` is not a standard method for Java strings.

Comment: This is Java**Script**. The question is about **Java**. On top of that, you're answering a question asked 8 **years** ago, which already had an accepted solution. Please try to avoid 'bumping' old questions, unless you found a new and markedly improved solution to the problem. Also remember to provide some [**context surrounding your code**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) to help explain it. Check out the documentation on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)