# str.setCharAt(index,'X')

Tags: java

Is there a way to use str.charAt(index) to replace a specific char by index?
Something like this:

```
str.setCharAt(1,'X'); // replace 2nd char with 'X'
```

Is there any easy way to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on the source of `str` you may be able to do something like this:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("Test string");
str.setCharAt(1, 'X');
str.toString();
```

If you have a string that you are piecing together and modifying a lot, it makes more sense to use a `StringBuilder` instead of a string. However, if you are modifying a `String` from another method call, the other answers may be more appropriate.

Comment: wait!! I'm new to this, but java has StringBuffer and StringBuilder? why don't they just merge all these functions in the basic String class?

Comment: @evilReiko A String is immutable. I.e. once created it can't change. Its very efficient to use when its not intended to change, but if you need to change its contents you need to use StringBuilder or its Threadsafe cousin StringBuffer. If you are not working in a multithreaded environment (or your StringBuilder instance is only accessible from one thread) a StringBuilder is normally enough.

Comment: If you have a StringBuffer which is being updated by multi-threads I suggest you change your program so it doesn't ;)

Comment: Each of the three classes fulfills a specific role, as others have pointed out. One nifty caveat is that the compiler will replace calls to string concatenation to the creation of a StringBuilder, adding elements, and calling toString() at the end. This is the case when you "add" strings, objects, and primitives together. If you concatenate static strings, e.g. "string1" + "string2", the compiler will perform the concatenation in place, rather that delegating to the JVM at runtime. This is all tangential to this discussion but nice to know regardless.

Answer (score 4):

`StringBuilder` has a `setCharAt()` method (thanks @John for identifying that you should use it over `StringBuffer`):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
sb.setCharAt(1, 'X');
str = sb.toString();
```

Or you can use `substring()`, which is a little messy and less efficient:

```
str = str.substring(0, 1) + 'X' + str.substring(2);
```

Strings are immutable (well, [sort of](http://directwebremoting.org/blog/joe/2005/05/26/1117108773674.html)), so you have to create a new string and assign it to `str`.

Comment: Why use `StringBuffer` and the overhead of synchronization for a temporary variable not accessed by multiple threads? `StringBuilder` is more appropriate here (see my answer).

Comment: @John Because I was unaware of the distinction. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is more or less efficient than the other proposed solutions (though it seems simpler):

```
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
chars[1] = 'X';
str = new String(chars);
```

This is the same approach suggested in [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028095/how-can-i-exchange-the-first-and-last-characters-of-a-string-in-java/1028124#1028124).

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string at the index, insert the character and then concatenate the remaining part of the string:

```
public static String replaceCharAt(String s, int pos, char c)
{
    return s.substring(0, pos) + c + s.substring(pos + 1);
}
```

Where `s` is the input string.

Comment: That is really inefficient with all the generating of new strings and doesn't look very pretty either. Why not use one of the many methods already supplied in StringBuilder?

Comment: The OP asked for an easy way and did not provide any prerequisites, like efficiency. Also, it is always valuable to learn different ways to perform tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the StringBuilder class (not StringBuffer), it has a replace method looking like `sb.replace(0, 1, "X");` or if it's always just a char use `sb.setCharAt(0, 'X');` and is very useful anyway when you want to mutate strings.