# Using a For Loop to set all lower case to uppercase

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, charat

How do you use a for loop to set all the lower cases of a string into upper cases?

This is what I did, but I get two compiler errors,

> - The method `setCharAt(int, char)` is undefined for the type
>     `java.lang.String` [line 7]
> - Array cannot be resolved [line 12]

```
public static String allUpperCases(String toEncode){
    int length = toEncode.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
      char ch = toEncode.charAt(i);
      if (Character.isLowerCase(ch)){
        toEncode.setCharAt(i, Character.toUpperCase(ch));
      }
    }

    return toEncode;
  }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576513/str-setcharatindex-x

Comment: What part of the error message, "The method setCharAt(int, char) is undefined for the type java.lang.String[line 7]", is confusing? It describes exactly what you did wrong, and it states what line the mistake is on. We need to know what part you don't understand in order to write a helpful answer. Otherwise, we are just going to repeat what the error says in different words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a single operation!

```
my_string = my_string.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a for loop to set a string to lower or upper case. You can use `myString = myString.toLowerCase();`. Conversely, there is the opposite: `myString = myString.toUpperCase();`. You should really read the [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

With regards to your errors:

The `String` type does not have a `setCharAt()` function in Java. That's because a `String`, at least in Java, is an immutable type. When you "change" a string, unless you're using a `StringBuilder` or modifying the underlying `char` array, you are actually assigning a new `String` to the variable.

I can't diagnose your `Array cannot be resolved` error, as I don't see an array in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want your String all uppercase, there is a function in Java:

```
yourstring.toUpperCase();
```