# Removing a single char from a string of letters based on a number position in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, int

To give some context to the title, let's say I have an array of INTs. So, for example (1,2,3,4,5).
Each number in the array represents a char in a string. So if the string is hello then array[3] is going to represent "l".
What is the most efficient or simplest way to remove a char from a string, replace the char and then add it back into the string?
So using the example above I could change "l" to "d", add it back to the string so my final string is "hedlo".

here is part of my code:

method used for max:

```
 public static int getMax(int[] inputArray){ 
    int maxValue = inputArray[0]; 
    for(int i=1;i < inputArray.length;i++){ 
      if(inputArray[i] > maxValue){ 
         maxValue = inputArray[i]; 
      } 
     } 
    return maxValue; 
    }
```

here is the code for using the max value in the array as the position in the string results to edit. The char to edit should be replaced with an "m" in the actual case

```
 int max = getMax(array);
    results.setCharAt(max, 'm');
    String result = results.toString();
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a site to find someone to do your homework.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13386289/8437540

Comment: Please see [about asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You must provide at least some example of what you've already tried. But to answer you're question, yes, it can easily be done.

Comment: Nothing yet, I wasn't even sure if it was possible. I am quite new to java, I could do it in VB but wasn't sure if similar thinking could be used in Java.

Comment: Please try something yourself first. Ask then a specific question if you get any trouble.

Comment: want2learn, I don't think what the code is for is really of concern.

Comment: The link that @AbdullahAftab mentions, along with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576513/str-setcharatindex-x/4576556) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can easiyl be done. Below I have some code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4576556/9354346

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("hello");
str.setCharAt(2, 'd');
String result = str.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing why you're doing this, I'm not sure exactly what to recommend but here's something to think about. ASCII characters have numerical values associated with them. [Table.](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)

If you cast an int to a char, it will convert it to that value. So like,

```
char c = (char) 97;
```

would evaluate to 'a.' If you want 'a' to start at 1, you could just add 96 to everything.

To convert, you could add to an int the difference in the table. So from 'a' to 'd', add 3.

EDIT:

I answered this assuming you were changing an array of ints that was representing a string. Re-reading the question, I'm not sure that's what you're doing! If you need to change a character of a string to a different character, you can use the substring function to grab characters before the change, and after the change and put the new character in the middle.

```
String x = "Hello";
x = x.substring(0,2) + 'd' + x.substring(3);
```

This makes x say "Hedlo."